# Can the .ssh directory be placed in a different location than under $HOME?

Tags: ssh

My company has a containerization system that causes our effective home directory to be different than the *nix one for the session.  I have scripts in place to deal with that distinction.

For the keys and config file under `./ssh` an option would be to manually sync/copy from the effective to the physical home dir's using a script. But a preferred solution would be to simply use one under the effective directory e.g. `/home/user/redirected_home/.ssh` instead of `/home/user/.ssh`.    Is this supported by `ssh` ?

Comment: You can at least set an alternative `AuthorizedKeysFile` location, via the server's `sshd_config` file - that's often done where the user's home dir is encrypted for example.

Comment: Can this not be solved with a simple symbolic link?

Comment: I suppose the link could be re-created for each new re-instantiation of the root directory. That's a somewhat better solution than doing `cp -Rp` each time